# Why is cURL's verbose mode only printing to my apache error file when Apache is stopped?

Tags: php, apache, logging, curl

I have PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu Server 14.04.01 using the PHP cURL wrapper 7.35.0. My php.ini file (in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`) has the following settings set:

```
error_reporting = 999999999 (setting it back to "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED" has no effect)
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
track_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
```

My VirtualHost config looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /path/to/files
        <Directory />
            Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel info
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My PHP code looks like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

When I make requests to this php file, I see the results so I know the script is getting run, but there are no entries in the log file. Once I stop apache (`service apache2 stop`), I get all of the error messages from cURL that I want to see.

I would rather each request's logs be printed to error.log immediately. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `CURLOPT_STDERR` points to some buffered location by default. Tying it to php's stderr, as in

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));
```

appears to sort this out.